# Class is returning null instead of the string property assigned to its constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter by following an online course. I'm at the lesson of creating classes. So we have to create a class that has a `string` and a `bool` property. Below is this class:

```
 class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}){
    q = questionText;
    a = questionAnswer;
  }
}
```

I then create a list of these classes in `main.dart` and assign values to their constructors:

```
List<Question> questionsAnswers = [
    Question(q:'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', a:false),
    Question(q:'Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.', a:true),
    Question(q:'A slug\'s blood is green.', a:true),
  ];
```

And then try to get the value from the above lists to a `Text` widget:

```
Text(
                questionsAnswers[questionNumber].questionText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
```

where `questionNumber` is an integer that is incremented, its currently at 0.

But this does not compile and I get the error:

> The following assertion was thrown building QuizPage(dirty, state:
> _QuizPageState#558aa): A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion:
> line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

It is definitely returning `null` instead of the string assigned to it. When I change the problematic line to `questionsAnswers[questionNumber].questionText.toString(),` I get `null` printed on screen.

Why is it failing to get the string value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignments to the instance variables in your `Question` constructor are backwards. The constructor should be

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

The Dart Language Tour has some examples for the initialization of instance variables here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Here's a pen with the working example: https://codepen.io/ezrayoung/pen/ExPobMB

Answer (score 2):

Ttry to do:

```
    class Question{
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}){
    questionText =q;
    questionAnswer =a;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is right, but it is more helpful to describe the source of the error so others may avoid in the future. In the example, the error is how the constructor was assigning the fields value. Dart assigns the right side of the expression to the left side variable. 

so the constructor syntax was:
`q = questionText; a = questionAnswer;`
since q and a are parameters in the constructor call, not the class fields remain null. The right declaration is:
`questionText = q; questionAnswer = a;`

Answer (score 1):

@darkness answer solves your problem. However, I feel that having your params to be words instead of single characters add to the readability for other coders. I have changed your variables for better readability

```
class Question {
      Question({this.text, this.answer});
      final String text;
      final bool answer;
    }


List<Question> questions = [
    Question(text:'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', answer: false),
  ];

print(questions.first.text)
print(questions.first.answer)
```